# Rails 4 & SimpleCov: lib/tasks/cucumber.rake included in coverage report for SimpleCov?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simplecov

I have the following code at the top of `spec/spec_helper.rb` and `features/support/env.rb` (SimpleCov merging RSpec & Cucumber coverage results):

```
require 'simplecov'
```

I also have the following code in a `.simplecov` file in the project root:

```
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

However, for some reason, `lib/tasks/cucumber.rake` is included in the coverage...

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: In spec folder there is file rcov.opts, in this file we have –exclude option. We can append our path of files to this. for example i want to exclude helpers , sweepers folders, so just add/modify –exclude “helpers/*,app/sweepers/*”.                                                                                In RSpec-1, the rake task would read in rcov options from an rcov.opts file. This is ignored by RSpec-2. RCov options are now set directly on the Rake task:

    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rcov) do |t|
      t.rcov_opts =  %q[--exclude "spec/,gems/,features/*"]
    end

Answer (score 0):

In spec folder there is file rcov.opts, in this file we have –exclude option.

We can append our path of files to this. 
for example i want to exclude helpers , sweepers folders, so just add/modify

```
–exclude “helpers/*,app/sweepers/*”.
```

In RSpec-1, the rake task would read in rcov options from an rcov.opts file.

This is ignored by RSpec-2. RCov options are now set directly on the Rake task:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rcov) do |t| 
    t.rcov_opts = %q[--exclude "spec/,gems/,features/*"] 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SimpleCov with RSpec before, but typically I would handle this type of scenario by adding a filter to SimpleCov after calling start. In your case it might mean changing the start call in `.simplecov` from

```
SimpleCov.start "rails"
```

to

```
SimpleCov.start("rails") do
  add_filter "lib/tasks/cucumber.rake"
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. :( - I'm using Cucumber and TestUnit in my project, but `simplecov` reports 0.0% covered.

Comment: @etagwerker, is your project in a public repo that I could take a look at?

Comment: no, but I have created an issue in `simplecov`: https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/587